# MongoDB: any other options than embedded doc? (not duplicate one)

Tags: mongodb

Say, I have two documents: Doca and Docb. Doca is like kind of common attribute, which can be part of Docb and other docs.

Use embedded document. but Doca could be duplicate at many places since it will be used by other documents like Docb. MongoDB looks encourage this kind of duplicating.

But I'm still wondering any better option is there.

Ideally, It won't be better if I can use kind of referencing in one collection like below

```
Doca { _id : "doca", ... //attributes }

Docb { ..., ref: "doca", ... }
```

Then, when I do query, I can query those sub doc as well. Can I do like this in MongoDB without using embedded doc?

Comment: sounds like you want something relational, which is not what mongodb is for.

Comment: Yes, I have some same feeling as yours. My thinking was still too 'relational'. So I should embed Docb into Doca whenever it's needed?

Comment: what driver will you be using?

Comment: Good point. I haven't thought about the driver. MongoDB in CPAN for Perl, very possible. It doesn't have many facilities like PHP's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb: any other way apart from reference and embedded doc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110945/mongodb-any-other-way-apart-from-reference-and-embedded-doc)